# DELETE query "ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away"

Tags: mysql

#### Summary:

I have 250 miljon rows in `P`-table and 100 000 in the `J`-table. I'm trying to remove all rows from the `P`-table that lack relation to the `J`-table.

#### Expected result:

Every row missing a relation *(about 100 000 has a relation)* will be removed from the `P`-table.

#### The query I'm using:

```
DELETE P 
FROM P 
LEFT JOIN J ON J.P_id = P.id 
WHERE J.id IS NULL;
```

#### The error I receive:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
```

#### What I tried:

```
SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout=63000;
SET wait_timeout=63000;

/* ... followed by the query stated above ... */
```

---

### Question

How can I reach the expected result?

---

### Edit

#### *Additional information - processlist*

So I guess the query is still running..

```
+-----+------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db      | Command | Time  | State        | Info                                                                                                 |
+-----+------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 540 | root | localhost | scraper | Query   | 63298 | Sending data | DELETE Domain_Page FROM Domain_Page LEFT JOIN StructuredData_Joppli ON StructuredData_Joppli.Domain_ |
| 556 | root | localhost | scraper | Query   |     0 | NULL         | show processlist                                                                                     |
+-----+------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: A Google search returns [this MySql manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html) as the first result. Have you started working down the list of possible causes?

Comment: try to limit query. LIMIT 1000, and loop this query to slow down process usage

Comment: @ПавелИванов You can't set a limit on a join delete query

Comment: @ErikLandvall okay, do it like subquery, it will allow to use limit.

Comment: @Jon I have looked at the list and can't find anything useful. I'm the only one using the server witch narrows down the possibilities a lot. The issue should of course be mentioned somewhere in that list though..

Comment: @ErikLandvall  sqlfiddle for you with subquery http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd562/1

Comment: @ПавелИванов thanks, I tried the subquery but was greeted by `ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction` I also tried a few different versions. This was done during a session that had a low timeout to begin with. While doing this I noticed there was a process still running with the old query. See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 DELETE P
 FROM P
```

to

```
 DELETE 
 FROM P
```

Comment: When deleting with a join you must indicate like `DELETE p FROM p`

Answer (score 0):

If there is no index relation, try to delete in smaller portions.

```
DELETE P 
FROM P 
LEFT JOIN J ON J.P_id = P.id 
WHERE J.id IS NULL LIMIT 10000;
```

Edit

What about using a subquery? Please try with a test table first.

```
DELETE p FROM p
JOIN 
(SELECT J.P_Id 
 FROM J LEFT JOIN P ON J.P_Id=P.Id 
 WHERE j.Id IS NULL LIMIT 1000
) P2 ON p.Id=P2.P_Id
```

Comment: I tried a few different subquerys but noticed that the old process was still running. See updated question.
I will wait for this query to finish before I try this subquery with a longer timeout.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete 
from P left join J ON J.P_id = P.id 
where J.id IS NULL
```

IF the column is not NULL but just blank you would need to do something like this:

```
delete 
frome P 
left join J ON J.P_id = P.id 
where J.id=''
```